# How to customize the custom options in magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

For example

In magento have added two custom options as Size(S,L,XL) and Color(RED,BLUE).

But in frontend i have to show the size as

[image: Size]

And color as

[image: Color]

Ideas welcome.

Comment: Make provision for adding/uploading S.png, L.png, RED.png etc icons in the back end based on these icons labels.

Answer (score 0):

Use this free extension. It helps you and I use the same.  http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/gala-color-swatches-free-1.html

Answer (score 0):

there is free extension available for that

http://marius-strajeru.blogspot.in/2013/10/easylife-switcher-extension.html

it work for me